# LibGdx falling object

Tags: java, android, ios, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to code a LibGDX game.

Currently i am trying to make add an image that falls from the top of the screen to the bottom then reappears over the screen and falls again, I also need to find a way that can detect collision with a player (which I will have to learn how to properly add a player next) .

The problem is I don't have any experience in this part of Libgdx i am still fairly new.

This is what i have tried so far,

```
Image image;

public Beam(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
    image.setPosition(LevelSmash.HEIGHT, LevelSmash.WIDTH);
}

public void update(){
    image.setY(image.getY() - 1);
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch sb){
    sb.begin();
    //Draw image?
    sb.end();
}
```

I already know it is very bad, I don't know which LibGDX classes to use, I was wondering if it was Body or something?

**EDIT**

Updated Code

```
public class Beam extends Sprite{

Image image;

Body body;

public Beam(World world) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(100, 300);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(20f);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.4f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f;
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    circle.dispose();

    body.setUserData(this);

    setRegion(new Texture("beam.png"));
}

public void update(float dt){
}

public Body getBody(){
    return body;
}}
```

Comment: What is the reason for using box2d (the fixtures)? If you are not sure how to move a sprite and do collision I think you really don't need to start messing with a physics engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should stay away from box2d for now. It seems like overkill to use it for this project.

Here is an example of how you could solve it:

Beam.class:

```
public class Beam{
    private Rectangle bound;
    private TextureRegion texture;
    private float weight = 10; //or gravity or however you want to think about it

    public Beam(float x, float y, float width, float height){
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("beam.png"));
        bound = new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
    }

    public void update(float delta){
        bound.y -= weight*delta;
    }

    public Rectangle getBound(){
        return bound;
    }

    public Texture getTexture(){
        return texture;
    }
}
```

You get the beam to the top of the screen by just changing the bound.y

```
beam.getBound().y = newValue;
```

You can do this on the object itself or by whereever it makes sense in you game.

Then when you add a player you give that object a bound too and you can do simple collision with:

```
if( player.getBound().overlaps(beam.getBound())){
    //collision
}
```

The bound is a Rectangle object from libgdx. It holds an x and y coordinate and a width and height. Using a Rectangle makes moving the object and collision detection very simple.

EDIT:

Drawing the texture from render():

```
public void render(float delta){
    ...
    beam.update(delta);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(beam.getTexture(), beam.getBound().x, beam.getBound().y);
    spriteBatch.end();

}
```

Or have beam draw itself:

```
public void render(float delta){
    ...
    beam.update(delta);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    beam.draw(spritebatch);
    spriteBatch.end();
}
```

in the beam class:

```
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
    spriteBatch.draw(texture, bound.x, bound.y);
}
```

Comment: How would i add a texture that follows the rectangle?

Comment: The beam class has a texture. You just draw it where the bound is.
I edited the answer and added two examples how to draw it.

Comment: Thanks! So far this is working, one problem i had was with you code i used texture.getHeight and texture.getWidth in the constructor when i manually added them it works!

Comment: Do you happen to know if 0, 0 is the left bottom corner or where? I'm trying to make it so when its down off the screen it reappears at the top but if(y < 0)
            y = LevelSmash.HEIGHT / 2; makes it appear in the middle

Comment: LeveSmash.HEIGHT / 2 is the middle. If you take half the height you get the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. There are two ways to do it- one is to use Box2D (the physics system; you can find [documentation here on the libGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d)), or build your own movement and collision detection (which isn't hard, and may actually be better for a simple game).

I recommend that you take some time to read through the libGDX wiki articles first to better understand the library. There are tutorials which teach you how to draw images and handle movement. That being said, here are a few tips:

In your update method, you have the image moving down 1 pixel each frame. This will become a problem because different computers will execute frames at different speeds which means your game will be faster on one computer compared to another. Instead of saying `image.setY(image.getY() - 1);`, you might consider something like `image.setY(imsage.getY() - speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());`- this will ensure that you move "speed" pixels/units each second, regardless of how fast or slow the computer is.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! I got a circle body now but i don't understand how to attach a texture to that body..? [Code: http://pastebin.com/d1B3dHdf ]

Comment: Take a look at the wiki link I posted; it has a section that discusses how you might attach a sprite to a body and then keep them in sync: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#sprites-and-bodies

Comment: This is what i have tried doesn't seem to be working? http://pastebin.com/XjpbSUZu

Comment: It doesn't draw the texture